# Three20 Empty Table View when Model is Not Finish Loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

The situation here is, I have an application with a tab bar, and each tab has a TTTableViewController with Datasource and TTURLRequest Models

When I do this series of actions, i get this no data table:

(1) While my fist view is loading, and the items is not yet displayed (Three20 Loading...)

(2) then I switch to another tab

(3) Then go back to that first view, I get an empty table. but when
I tried to breakpoint and look into the visible cells, the model, the datasource, they have values, but how come it displayed an empty table.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a quick fix for my problem, i know this is not the best way.So what I did was to set a private boolean if it needs to invalidate the model, when user moves to another view and while the model is not yet loaded, i set the flag _isNeedtToInvalidateModel=YES

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(_isNeedToInvalidateModel) {
        [self invalidateModel];
        _isNeedToInvalidateModel = NO;
    }

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if(![self.model isLoaded]) {
        _isNeedToInvalidateModel = YES;
    }
}
```

Somehow it does not show the empty table view anymore